# Understanding Floating point precision analysis for Parallel Reduction

Tags: opencl, mpi, gpu, multicore

I am trying to analyze how reduction (parallel) can be used to add a large array of floating point numbers and precision loss involved in it. Definitely reduction will help in getting more precision compared to serial addition . I'll be really thankful if you can direct me to some detailed source or provide some insight for this analysis. Thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a specific question; can you rephrase so that you have some concrete questions, rather than just asking for general knowledge?

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. Actually I came across a question as follows: Given a array of 1 million numbers(double precision floating point number between 1 and 2) , where the numbers follow a gaussian distribution with mean value of 1.4. What will be the best approximated sum of these numbers. Whats the gain in precision if we do a parallel reduction for adding these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Every primitive floating point operation will have a rounding error; if the result is x then the rounding error is <= c * abs (x) for some rather small constant c > 0.

If you add 1000 numbers, that takes 999 additions. Each addition has a result and a rounding error. The rounding error is small when the result is small. So you want to adjust the order of additions so that the average absolute value of the result is as small as possible. A binary tree is one method. Sorting the values, then adding the smallest two numbers and putting the result back into the sorted list is also quite reasonable. Both methods keep the average result small, and therefore keep the rounding error small.

Comment: Thanks ! That helped. I found a related post for it . [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139656/precision-in-sum-reduction-kernel-with-floats?rq=1)

Comment: Kahan summation is another widely used method of managing floating point rounding duration accumulation

Comment: Perhaps also this paper will help: [A Comparison Of Methods For Accurate Summation](http://www.sigsam.org/bulletin/articles/147/sumnums.pdf).

Comment: This Fortran code at LBNL and the publications from those authors are probably of interest: [http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/).